# How to use well-known chaotic skew tent map to permute an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, permutation, grayscale

I would like to  permute a grayscale image to get a random looking image using  an orbit `$\left\{z_{i}\right\}$` of the well-known chaotic skew tent map defined by

[image]
where the initial condition `$z_{0} \in(0,1)$` and the control parameter `$q \in(0,1)$` are imported from a key.

How can I do  it using python?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using numpy

```
def tent_map(img, q):
    
    img_new = np.zeros_like(img)
    
    # condition 1
    cond1= np.where((0<img)&(img<q))
    # condition 2
    cond2= np.where((q<img)&(img<1))
    
    img_new[cond1] = img[cond1] / q
    img_new[cond2] = (1- img[cond2]) / (1-q)
    
    return img_new
```